# Return something from functions like swap and vswap

Tags: clojure

Oftentimes I have a volatile or atom containing a deeply nested structure like so:

```
{ :deeply { :nested { ... } } }
```

`swap!` returns the full, updated structure. But instead I'd sometimes like to return other information (like e.g. a kind of "diff" with information about what I changed, especially in cases where I change multiple things).

One thing that comes to mind is defining another volatile variable for that, and storing that information I'd like to return from `swap!` inside that volatile variable for later consumption.

That would certainly work, but I wonder if there isn't something more idiomatic and functional that I'm missing.

One more functional style way to do it would be changing the layout of that deep structure to something like

```
{:state { :deeply { :nested { ... } } } :diff nil }
```

where I put the deep structure into the `:state` entry, and the most recent diff into the `:diff` entry.

Is there anything idiomatic that people are using which I'm missing?

Comment: Are you talking about something like [Om's cursors](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Cursors)?

Comment: @akond Reading your article: It seems Om is somewhat similar to my latter possible solution, in that it keeps all state in one atom. Cursors store a position (a path) inside that atom, and Om manages the cursors' and atom's state and applies changes (or defers their application, if in the render phase). I don't think it directly addresses my question, though.

Answer (score 6):

This is easy to do with [`swap-vals!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap-vals!) (only on Clojure 1.9+) and [`clojure.data/diff`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.data/diff):

```
(def a (atom {:deeply {:nested "value"}}))

(let [[old new] (swap-vals! a assoc-in [:deeply :other] "foo")]
  (clojure.data/diff old new))
=> (nil
    {:deeply {:other "foo"}}
    {:deeply {:nested "value"}})
```

`swap-vals!` is like `swap!` but it returns the old *and* new value. `diff` shows you what's only in the left value, only in the right value, and what's in both values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `swap-vals!` which I didn't know yet. However, my intention here is not to have to figure out the diff afterwards - which may be costly, especially when the data structure is huge, and the changes are few. Although I guess thanks to structural sharing of clojure's persistent data structures it wouldn't be too bad. But inside `swap!`, while changing the data, I can easily produce the diff while I'm going.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky If you can post an example of how you'd want a diff to look for a given input and change, I might be able to help more.